# Achieving mTLS with AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, nlb, amazon-alb

If I have an ALB in my infrastructure with ECS target groups downstream, will SSL/TLS always be terminated at the ALB?

If so, are my only options ELB/NLB to preserve the SSL/TLS context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALB always terminates https, but can create a new https session to your target servers if you set them up with certificates. Information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html). Note that you can't use AWS Certificate Manager for servers, you need third party certificates.

If you want TLS terminated on the servers themselves your best option is to use an NLB. ELB are generally not used these days unless you have a very good reason, they're first gen.

Comment: A new session would satisfy my requirements. How do I create a new https session to my target group?

Comment: Answer edited. You set up your servers with https certificates and make sure the target group is set to use https

Comment: Why can't you use AWS cert manager?

Comment: It seems that the cert is not validated in the ALB, so it wouldn't be as secure as end to end mTLS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-routing-configuration

Comment: I can never remember if self signed certs are ok, looks like they are. You can't use AWS Certificate Manager because it's not possible to export a private key to put on your instance.

Comment: Couldn't the server just do `acm:exportcertificate` and that would return the exported file contains the certificate, the certificate chain, and the encrypted private key. @Tim

Comment: Seems like you can export cert/ca/private key from private CA, not public

Comment: Exactly, and a private CA costs about $600 per month from memory. For my personal servers I use Let's Encrypt certificates with certbot. Commercially I tend to use self signed certs unless there's a good reason to use Let's Encrypt / commercial / something else.

Answer (score 1):

As of 26 Nov 2023: mutual TLS is now supported in AWS ALBs.
With Mutual authentication (mTLS) enabled, you can configure how listeners handle requests that present client certificates. This includes how your Application Load Balancer authenticates certificates and the amount of certificate metadata that is sent to your backend targets.

Mutual authentication has two options. The Passthrough option sends all the client certificate chains received from the client to your backend application using HTTP headers. The mTLS-enabled Application Load Balancer gets the client certificate in the handshake, establishes a TLS connection, and then sends whatever it gets in HTTPS headers to the target application. The application will need to verify the client certificate chain to authenticate the client.

See blog here.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mutual-authentication-for-application-load-balancer-to-reliably-verify-certificate-based-client-identities/